# What tools can I use to generate X.509 certificates?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, x509

When I Google this, I find many places that [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547647/how-to-make-x-509-certificate) using the `PluralSight` tool to generate a certificate, but this tool is no longer available.

Does anyone know of another tool that will easily create and install a certificate?

**Edit:**

Tool available in a new URL: [Plural-sight self cert tool](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/selfcert-create-a-self-signed-certificate-interactively-gui-or-programmatically-in-net).

Comment: What language do you need this in? StackOverflow is about programming first of all, not about admin tools.

Comment: The link to Pluralsight self cert tool just returns 404 now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use openssl to create self signed certificates. Several tutorial are available, following being one of them.

http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

Comment: Thansk I found this tool - http://www.mobilefish.com/services/ssl_certificates/ssl_certificates.php would these certs be good for local testing WCF with a https:// ?

Comment: Yes, they should be fine. Why not try one and see, since it should only take a minute to generate? Make sure the common name you choose matches the domain of the server, as seen by your browser (e.g. "localhost").

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an admin tool you already got some good answers; however if you need to generate certificates from code here are a couple alternatives you can try out (full disclosure: I am a developer for these products), [Versile Python](http://web.archive.org/web/20160331132945/http://versile.com/products/vpy/) (Git repos: [python 2](https://gitorious.org/versile/versile-python.git/),  [python 3](https://gitorious.org/versile/versile-python3.git/)) and [Versile Java](http://web.archive.org/web/20160404135140/https://versile.com/products/vjava/) ([Git repo](https://gitorious.org/versile/versile-java.git/)). They do not fully implement X.509, but enough to create basic certificates including some of the main certificate extensions.